# AWS DB Subnet is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

I have a custom VPC which has 6 public subnets in 6 AZs.

When I tried to create Aurora Serverless, I do see my VPC in the VPC dropdown but there is only 1 item 'Create new DB subnet group'. 
[image]

I'm expecting my VPC has available subnet groups already.

I have researched a lot already, even compare another VPC (which is working) with my VPC, I don't see anything differences from VPC to Subnet to RouteTable to Security Group ...

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bundle the subnets you want to use on your instance on a `db subnet group`, you can't add the subnets directly.

It is very easy, [as seeing here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html)

Comment: Bundle the subnets? Could you explain more? I went the the link many times but I don't see the concept you are mentioning. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Just look for subnet groups

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot.